# ID pine by cones and seeds

Tags: identification, bonsai, conifers, pines

Can anyone ID a pine by its cones and seeds only? I collected some cones for seeds (starting material for bonsai). I know of a little field in the outer regions of Amsterdam, where there are some pine trees. According to the tree [map](https://maps.amsterdam.nl/bomen/) (published by the municipality) the field contains as well *Pinus sylvestris* as *Pinus nigra* trees. However, I couldn't see any difference between the trees, for me they all seemed the same species.

Is there anyone here with a trained eye that can distinguish both species based on the cones and seeds?

[image: Pinus]

[image: Cones]

Comment: Pinus nigra vs P. sylvestris: Needles are longer and same green on both side. Trunk should be dark to the top. Keys say that P. nigra fruits are more glossy and without (or very short) peduncle (but I never look for it).

Comment: Thank you @GiacomoCatenazzi, this is very helpful! The cones I have seem to have peduncle (more *P. sylvestris* I would then say). I will go back sometime to check some needles.